# full width white background color on ul .active item is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with 3 columns (col-md-3) and a div with 9 columns (col-md-9). The col-md-3 div have a blue background and a `<ul>` element. In this ul I have a class .active in the first element, and I want to give a background color of white to the active element.

The issue is that  I want a full width background white color but its not working, the white background color is not occupying the full width of the col-md-3 div. Do you know how to solve the issue?

Using .container-fluid instead of .container fix the issue but then the content is not aligned with the above divs that use .container not .container-fluid.

issue example: https://jsfiddle.net/1pmtxa7f/2/

html:

```
<div class="background-div">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 p-0">
                    <ul class="admin_menu mt-4">
                        <li class="active"><a href="">Item 0</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item 2 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item 3 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item 4<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 mt-4 bg-white">
                    Content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pseudo element to simulate the background and easily control it with position (use negative value for left/right to make it overflow the active element):

```css
.background-div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bg-white {
  background-color: white;
}

.admin_menu {
  list-style: none;
}

.admin_menu li {
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

li.active:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -150%;
  right: -150%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 0;
}

.admin_menu li a {
  color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="background-div">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 p-0">
        <ul class="admin_menu mt-4">
          <li class="active"><a href="">Item 0</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Item 2 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="">Item 3 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="">Item 4<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 mt-4 bg-white">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Also do you know why the menu dont stays with height:100% using .admin_menu{height:100%}?

Comment: @JohnX `height:100%` means 100% of the parent height, so if no heigh is specified for the parent it has no effect

Comment: Thanks, but add {height:100%} to the col-md-3 also dont works!

Comment: @JohnX yes same logic :) if there is no parent with any height specified it won't work on any element .. each element will be relative to the height of its parent. But you can avoid using % value and try `height:100vh` for example